# Spatial Query Postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a polygon city and polygon data that I import into PostgreSQL, PostGIS. These intersect with cities. The first thing I need to do is to print the id from the city table to the other table, but while doing this, it needs to get the id of the city where the polygon is located. I tried a few functions to do this but got an error. Can you help me design the SQL command line?

```
update maden_polygon set objectid = maden_polygon.ilce_id
from (SELECT maden_polygon.ilce_id as id ,ankara_ilce.objectid as ilce_id
FROM maden_polygon , ankara_ilce
WHERE st_intersects(maden_polygon.geom, ankara_ilce.geom)) as maden_polygon 
where maden_polygon.ilce_id = anakara_ilce.object_id
```

(ERROR:  table name "maden_polygon" specified more than once )

What I want to do is to print the objectid column in the ankara_ilce table to the mine_polygon ilce_id table.
While doing this,
Write the object_id of which mine is within the boundaries of which county.

```
SELECT 
maden_polygon.ilce_id as id ,
ankara_ilce.objectid as ad ,
ankara_ilce.adi as adi
from maden_polygon , ankara_ilce 
where St_intersects(ankara_ilce.geom , maden_polygon.geom  )  as sorgu
where maden_polygon.id = sorgu.id ;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 6: ...ntersects(ankara_ilce.geom , maden_polygon.geom  )  as sorgu

Comment: show the structure of tour tables and expected results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome! As mentioned, post some data, the result you want and what you have tried. If you have an error, post the error message...

Comment: @mlinth I updated my question please see

Comment: @Gregorz Grabek  I updated my question please see

Comment: Well, the error is that the alias you use "as maden_polygon" is the same as the table name. Change that to "intersect_query" or whatever, then your last where clause should be where "maden_polygon.ilce_id = intersect_query.object_id... Be aware that you can get unpredictable results if there are overlapping geographies...

Comment: SELECT 
maden_polygon.ilce_id as id ,
ankara_ilce.objectid as ad ,
ankara_ilce.adi as adi
From maden_polygon , ankara_ilce 
where St_intersects(ankara_ilce.geom , maden_polygon.geom  )  as sorgu
where maden_polygon.id = sorgu.id ;

Comment: I rewrote it like this but
syntax error at or near "as"
I got ..ntersects(ankara_ilce.geom , mine_polygon.geom ) as query error.
what can i write instead

Comment: Edit your question and post your revised query text...

Comment: I updated my question please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query is a simple as this:

```
UPDATE maden_polygon set objectid = ilce_id
FROM  ankara_ilce
WHERE st_intersects(maden_polygon.geom, ankara_ilce.geom)
```

BUT - note that the st_intersects can return multiple records per maden_polygon if your polygons overlap, and that might give you inconsistent results. You could try using st_contains instead (being aware that some records might not update that way). OR, you could match on the centroid of the one polygon e.g.

```
UPDATE maden_polygon set objectid = ilce_id
    FROM  ankara_ilce
    WHERE st_within(st_centroid(maden_polygon.geom), ankara_ilce.geom)
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you. This answer was informative for me. It's really much easier this way. I'm new to postgis so I stretched the code a lot